# onClickListener on RelativeLayout doesn't work

Tags: android

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/reviews_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:clickable="true">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/reviews"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using above code in xml.

```
    binding.apply {
        reviewsRoot.setOnClickListener {
            NavigateWithItemName(itemname)
            Log.i("click","click") //doesn't work
        }
    }
```

I'm using above code in `onCreateView` in `Fragment`.
I want to setOnClickListener on `RelativeLayout`, but it doesn't work when I click `RelativeLayout`..

I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RecyclerView` lying over the `RelativeLayout` is consuming the *clicks* that are intended to be handled by the layout. To prevent that You would have to set:

```xml
android:clickable="false"
```

on the `RecyclerView`. Now the layout will consume the *clicks*.